# AngularJS: Assign to scope value although attribute not set on element

Tags: angularjs

In my directive I create an isolate scope and assign to the `ngModel` in code. Here's my isolate scope:

```
scope: {
  ngModel: '=',
  value: "=",
  placeholder: "@"
}
```

Inside the `link` function I assign to `scope.ngModel`. That works fine if the `ng-model` attribute is set on the element, but when it's not it raises an error.

```
Error: Non-assignable model expression: undefined
```

What's the preferred way to check if the attribute exists? Do I have to do this explicitly with `element.hasAttribute` or am I doing it completely wrong?

Comment: You can't have optional two-way-binding (`=`). You could however optionally [`?^require`](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) the model, and have it injected to your link-function as the 4th parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ngModel-attribute is optional in your directive you have to check if it exist before you assign any value to the scope variable, or Angular will raise an error. I'd use `if( attrs.ngModel ){...}` or `element.attrs('ngModel')` to check if it's present.

With `ngModel` you also have the option of using the [ngModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController) in your directive link function. You do this by `require:'^ngModel'` (`^` if it's optional) and the ngModelController will be available as the fourth argument in your link controller (`link:function(scope,element,attrs,ngModelController){ ... }`).